# Binary Search in C++: Ascending + Descending Ordered Arrays

Tags: c++, binary-search

So I am trying to make a binary sort algorithm for my c++ class, but I keep getting a segmentation fault when my binarySearch function runs. No matter how hard me and my roommate look at it, we cant find the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
int binarySearch(int arr[], int k, int first, int last)
{
    if(arr[first] <= arr[last])
    {
        int mid = (first + last) / 2;

        if(k == arr[mid])
        {
            return mid;
        }
        else if (k < arr[mid])
        {
            return binarySearch(arr, k, first, mid-1);
        }
        else return binarySearch(arr, k, mid+1, last);
    }   
    else if(arr[first] >= arr[last])
    {
        int mid = (first + last) / 2;

        if(k == arr[mid])
        {
            return mid;
        }
        else if (k < arr[mid])
        {
            return binarySearch(arr, k, mid+1, last);
        }
        else return binarySearch(arr, k, first, mid-1);
    }
    else return -1;
}
```

After fixing the segmentation fault, I noticed I must have an error somewhere in my logic because the program keeps outputting that the key was unable to be found even though it exists in the array.

Comment: Take a look at http://mycodinglab.com/binary-search-algorithm-c/ and compare with what you have done.

Comment: Yeah, they did actually. I still ended up with a few logical errors, but I think that's more of a me problem haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works actually, if the element you are searching for is in the array. However, it does not catch incorrect input.

When calling the function, make sure that:

- `first` and `last` are between 0 and (array length - 1)
- `first < last`

eg: if the array has 10 elements, first and last must be between 0 and 9.

Try [this](http://goo.gl/t80ppj):

```
int main() {
    int a[] = {134, 232, 233, 234, 587, 623, 793, 802, 963, 1074};
    int b[] = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    int na = binarySearch(a, 587, 0, 9);
    int nb = binarySearch(b, 3, 0, 9);

    printf("na: %d\n", na);  // prints 'na: 4'
    printf("nb: %d\n", nb);  // prints 'nb: 7'
}
```

If the element you are searching for is *not* in the array,
then the recursion does never terminate,
you can fix that by adding the following to the head of `binarySearch()`:

```
if (first == last && k != arr[first])
    return -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a major concern, but to prevent overflow it is usual to rewrite `int mid = (first + last) / 2;` as `int mid = first + (last-first)>>1;`
It also seems that you will never hit the line `return -1` (the first two conditionals take care of all possible orderings)

An implementation (for strictly increasing, or decreasing array) could look like that

```
#include <cassert>

int binarySearch(int* array, int k, int l, int h, bool asc)
{
    if (l>h)
        return -1;
    int m = l + ((h - l) >> 1);
    if (array[m] == k)
        return m;
    else
    {
        if (array[m]>k)
            return binarySearch(array, k, (asc ? l : m + 1), (asc ? m - 1 : h),asc);
        else
            return binarySearch(array, k, (asc ? m + 1 : l), (asc ? h : m - 1),asc);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int ascArray[7] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    int descArray[7] = {7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    assert(binarySearch(ascArray, 7, 0, 6, ascArray[0] < ascArray[1]) == 6);
    assert(binarySearch(descArray, 7, 0, 6, descArray[0] < descArray[1]) == 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Did you notice what my logic mistake was by any chance? I'm not seeing it yet I keep getting incorrect output.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using if else if, you can try while loop:

```
int mid = (first + last)/2;
while(first<=last && arr[mid]!=k){
    if(arr[mid]<k)
        first=mid+1;
    else
        last=mid-1;
    mid = (first + last)/2;

}
if(arr[mid] == k){
    std::cout<<"Found"<<std::endl;
}else{
    std::cout<<"Not Found"<<std::endl;
}
```

Instead you can use vector, that makes it very easy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(){

int arrint[] = {3,5,2,1,7,6,9,4,8,10};
vector<int> vector1(arrint,arrint+10);

sort(vector1.begin(),vector1.end());
int n;
cout<<"Enter element to search: ";
cin>>n;
cin.ignore();
cout<<endl;

if(binary_search(vector1.begin(),vector1.end(),n)){
    cout<<"Found: "<<n<<endl;
}else{
    cout<<n<<" Not Found"<<endl;
}


//cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `first>=last`. I think the crash is because you don't find the element in the array.